# how to update crosstab values in python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

I tried to change value of crosstab with normal noise that I gave. But I can't update it after I change it. Can you please help me for it?

```
cross_tab1 = pd.crosstab(data[0], [data[1], data[2]], rownames=['data0'], colnames=['data1', 'data2'])
c1 = cross_tab1.unstack()


for (a, b, c), count in c1.iteritems():
    count = np.round(count + np.random.normal(0, 2.0)).clip(min=0)
    cross_tab1.loc(a,b,c, int(count))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for assign new values and last for `DataFrame` `unstack` with transposing:

```
for (a, b, c), count in c1.iteritems():
    count = np.round(count + np.random.normal(0, 2.0)).clip(min=0)
    c1.loc[a,b,c] = int(count)

df = c1.unstack(2).T
```

But better is use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df1 = cross_tab1.applymap(lambda x: np.round(x + np.random.normal(0, 2.0)).clip(min=0)) \
                .astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you. I used applymap for it